# how to randomly select n numbers from a column of matrix in octave

Tags: matlab, random, octave, particle-swarm

I am writing a Particle Swarm Optimization program and for that i want to initialize my particles. I want my particles to be initialized randomly from the column on which i am applying swarm optimization.
I am doing the program in Octave. I tried looking up for related commands but coundt find one. I want the answer in a matrix form.

 Help is appreciated. 

For Ex

```
733
590
495
479
569
560
305
433
319
244
256
255
398
340
```

from this i want 5 numbers like
 `305 590 495 244 340`

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
X = magic(10);

% pick k random numbers for column n:

k = 4;
n = 3;
X(randi(size(X,1), k, 1), n)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Dan and yeah my solution does not give the correct answer hence i deleted it

Comment: Just want to note that it does not neccesarily pick all different numbers. @SarasArya would it be a problem if two particles initialized on the same location?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin correct, in that case rather use `randperm`

Comment: @SarasArya Check also `randsample`, which covers both options: with and without replacement